# Try to read data through GNU Awk 3.1.7

Tags: linux, awk

Basically I want to read field number 21 or 51 but I'm not able read exact data I'm getting incorrect field.

```
Logic:- awk -F ',' '{print $21,$50}'
```

Data-->Test.txt

```
40968,SUR,ACT,1,Y,$GPNFT$,431068,SUR,MSUR,ACT,$DRS WRIGHT, HEWITT, GUNN & CHARLES$,$$,$PH8  0$,$DMB3005A$,UK,PH8  0AD,$BRAAN COTTAGE$,$$,$DUNKELD$,$PERTHSHIRE$,9772385,DOC,MED,ACT,Y,$GPNFT$,$METABOLIC$,$GAS ENDOSC$,M,$WRIGHT$,$GRAHAM$,$$,$$,$$,$$,$01-JAN-1959$,1982,,$U$,$Y$,$N$,$$,$N$,$002605139$,,$9772385$,$PH07$,$PH11$,$N$,$3005A$,$31-JUL-1997$,$00302620$,$00742230$,$$
594674,SUR,ACT,1,Y,$GVTRG$,431068,SUR,MSUR,ACT,$DRS WRIGHT, HEWITT, GUNN & CHARLES$,$$,$PH8  0$,$DMB3005A$,UK,PH8  0AD,$BRAAN COTTAGE$,$$,$DUNKELD$,$PERTHSHIRE$,99827837,DOC,MED,ACT,N,$GVTRG$,$$,$$,M,$GUNN$,$RODERICK$,$$,$$,$$,$$,$$,,,$U$,$N$,$N$,$$,$N$,$$,,$99827837$,$PH07$,$PH11$,$N$,$3005A$,$23-JUN-2010$,$00302620$,$00742230$,$$
```

Output

```
$DUNKELD$ $PH11$
$DUNKELD$ $PH11$
```

Expected Output

```
9772385,$3005A$
1430701,$3005A$
```

Any Idea

Comment: I think it should be `awk -F ',' '{print $23,$52}'`?

Comment: Too much unnecessary data: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `1430701` doesn't exist in your sample input so it's not going  to appear in your output.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk 4.* for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|([$][^$]+[$])' -v OFS=, '{print $21, $50}' file
9772385,$3005A$
99827837,$3005A$
```

You said you're using gawk 3.1.7 - that is extremely old, get a new version as you are missing a TON of useful functionality.

Comment: Ed Morton thanks for ur reply It is a single field $DRS WRIGHT, HEWITT, GUNN & CHARLES$ here $(") means separator

Comment: sorry I' m not able explain properly in above message $ means quote(") then fields is look like this "DRS WRIGHT, HEWITT, GUNN & CHARLES" it comes into one fields.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
awk -F ',' '{for(i=1; i <= NF;++i) {if ($i== 9772385) {print i, $i}} }' test.txt`
```

to find the `9772385` column, which is `23`.

```
awk -F ',' '{for(i=1; i <= NF;++i) { if($i ~ /3005A/) {print i, $i} } }' test.txt
```

this to find the `3005A`, which is `52`.

Maybe you need this:

```
lo@ubuntu:~$ awk -F ',' '{print $23,$52}' test.txt 
9772385 $3005A$
99827837 $3005A$
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply It is a single field  $DRS WRIGHT, HEWITT, GUNN & CHARLES$ here $(") means separator.

Answer (score 0):

This is CSV data, with "," as the field separator and "$" as the quote character. Use a language with a proper CSV parser. I like Ruby for this:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  csv_opts = {:col_sep => ",", :quote_char => "$"}
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift, csv_opts) {|row|
    puts CSV.generate_line([row[20], row[49]], csv_opts)
  }
' file
```

```
9772385,3005A
99827837,3005A
```

No quotes, because there are no inner commas in the output that require quoting. You can force the use of quotes

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  csv_opts = {:col_sep => ",", :quote_char => "$", :force_quotes => true}
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift, csv_opts) {|row|
    puts CSV.generate_line([row[20], row[49]], csv_opts)
  }
' file
```

```
$9772385$,$3005A$
$99827837$,$3005A$
```

Comment: thnx glenn for ur reply I'm very new to ruby when am I using above code I got below error -e:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
...$", :force_quotes => true} CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift, csv_opts)...